# Update materialized view azure adx?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, materialized-views

I am ingesting certain data into a table "TestEvents" with extent tagging

```
.ingest inline into table TestEvents with (tags = '[\"drop-by:test\"]')
```

The materialized "TestEventsMV "view associated with this table also gets updated with the new data.

Then, I want to drop the data in the source table based on the extent tag that I had set above.

```
.drop extents <| .show table TestEvents extents where tags has "drop-by:e2e-backend-test"
```

The data gets dropped from source table but since materialized view has its own retention policy, the ingested data still persists in the view.

There is a feature "autoUpdateSchema", which when set to true, the schema of the view is automatically updated based on the source table, but I could not find any option to update the content inside the view. Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. A materialized view is not impacted by records dropped from its source table, as documented here - [Impact of records ingested to or dropped from the source table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-views-limitations#impact-of-records-ingested-to-or-dropped-from-the-source-table).